# Nested seed loop for Users, Articles and Comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am seeding a local forum application using the below. The aim is to:

1. Create 10 Users
2. Give each user 10 articles
3. Write 10 comments for each article but randomly choose from the other 9 users

Not sure about randomly allocating the User to a comment. At the moment it simply uses the first user that was created. I think the fix is within the `Comment.create! user_id: user` part but not sure how to achieve this.

**seeds.rb**

```
10.times do |user|
  User.create!(id: "#{user}", email: "user_email#{user}@email.com", password: 'password', created_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now, username: "#{user}_username", confirmed_at: Time.now)

  # Create 10 articles 
  10.times do |article|
    Article.create!(title: "Article #{article}", body: "Body
      - #{article} - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris
      quis mauris turpis. Curabitur nec cursus lectus. In purus elit, bibendum in
      odio in, interdum porta neque. Nullam ultricies metus id lobortis interdum.
      Mauris volutpat nisl ac felis interdum ornare. Aenean interdum sollicitudin
      risus, et condimentum dolor molestie non. Integer lorem nisi, convallis non
      pulvinar quis, mollis suscipit sem. Phasellus luctus lacus id lobortis
      efficitur. Nam hendrerit tempus ante vel rhoncus. Phasellus vulputate odio non
      risus sodales interdum. Etiam vel bibendum erat. Proin sit amet velit eget leo
      vestibulum accumsan eu eget ligula. Vestibulum cursus ex tortor, eu semper leo
      maximus et. Sed turpis neque, sagittis vel mattis nec, tincidunt sit amet
      purus. Cras eget ullamcorper sem, sed ullamcorper mi. Donec in feugiat dolor.
      Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac
      turpis egestas. Quisque non pharetra nulla. Nam libero lacus, interdum ac
      viverra ac, tempus ac lorem. In venenatis quis nulla quis pretium. Nam
      placerat, arcu a euismod dignissim, nisi orci bibendum neque, eget venenatis
      nisl sapien vel mi. Quisque quis nisl vitae mi faucibus dapibus eget ac ipsum.
      Aliquam vehicula dolor blandit volutpat efficitur. Nulla eu nunc purus.
      Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque iaculis
      venenatis tellus id pharetra. Phasellus at aliquam erat, id finibus est.",
      status: 'public', created_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now, user_id: user)
  end  
  10.times do |comment|
    comment = 1
    Comment.create!(body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris
      quis mauris turpis. Curabitur nec cursus lectus. In purus elit, bibendum in
      odio in, interdum porta neque. Nullam ultricies metus id lobortis interdum.
      Mauris volutpat nisl ac felis interdum ornare. Aenean interdum sollicitudin
      risus, et condimentum dolor molestie non.", article_id: comment, user_id: user, created_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now)
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "status"
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.integer "views", default: 0
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_articles_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "commenter"
    t.text "body"
    t.integer "article_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "status"
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.index ["article_id"], name: "index_comments_on_article_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
  end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    t.integer "role", default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  include Visible
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 40 }
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 10_000 }

  has_noticed_notifications model_name: 'Notification'
end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  # include Visible

  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user
  has_rich_text :body

  after_create_commit :notify_recipient
  before_destroy :cleanup_notifications
  has_noticed_notifications model_name: 'Notification'

  private

  # Provide the parameters using .with to use them
  # in the methods and callbacks in the instance,
  # The deliver_later takes advantage of ACTIVE JOB, which allows
  # emails to be sent outside of the request response cycle
  def notify_recipient
    CommentNotification.with(comment: self, article:).deliver_later(article.user)
  end

  def cleanup_notifications
    notifications_as_comment.destroy_all
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :articles
  has_many :comments
  has_many :notifications, as: :recipient, dependent: :destroy

  def create
    # Create the user form params
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # Send the email
      UserNotifierMailer.send_signup_email(@user).deliver
      redirect_to(@user, notice: 'User created')
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :login)
  end

  # set user privileges within console using:
  # @user = User.first
  # @user.role = 1 # moderator
  # @user.save
  enum role: %i[user moderator admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, if: :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end

  def self.ransackable_attributes(_auth_object = nil)
    ['username']
  end
end
```

**Edited**
**seeds.rb**

```
def create_users(number)
  number.times.map{|i| User.create!(id: "#{i}", email: "user_email#{i}@email.com", password: 'password', created_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now, username: "#{i}_username", confirmed_at: Time.now)}
end

def create_articles_for_users(users, number)
  users.each do |user|
    number.times do |i|
      user.article.create!(title: "Article #{i}", body: "Body
      - #{i} - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris
      quis mauris turpis. Curabitur nec cursus lectus. In purus elit, bibendum in
      odio in, interdum porta neque. Nullam ultricies metus id lobortis interdum.
      Mauris volutpat nisl ac felis interdum ornare. Aenean interdum sollicitudin
      risus, et condimentum dolor molestie non. Integer lorem nisi, convallis non
      pulvinar quis, mollis suscipit sem. Phasellus luctus lacus id lobortis
      efficitur. Nam hendrerit tempus ante vel rhoncus. Phasellus vulputate odio non
      risus sodales interdum. Etiam vel bibendum erat. Proin sit amet velit eget leo
      vestibulum accumsan eu eget ligula. Vestibulum cursus ex tortor, eu semper leo
      maximus et. Sed turpis neque, sagittis vel mattis nec, tincidunt sit amet
      purus. Cras eget ullamcorper sem, sed ullamcorper mi. Donec in feugiat dolor.
      Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac
      turpis egestas. Quisque non pharetra nulla. Nam libero lacus, interdum ac
      viverra ac, tempus ac lorem. In venenatis quis nulla quis pretium. Nam
      placerat, arcu a euismod dignissim, nisi orci bibendum neque, eget venenatis
      nisl sapien vel mi. Quisque quis nisl vitae mi faucibus dapibus eget ac ipsum.
      Aliquam vehicula dolor blandit volutpat efficitur. Nulla eu nunc purus.
      Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque iaculis
      venenatis tellus id pharetra. Phasellus at aliquam erat, id finibus est.",
      status: 'public', created_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now, user_id: i)
    end
  end
end

def create_comments_for_articles(articles, users, number)
   articles.each do |article|
    comment_users = users.reject{|user| user == article.user}
    number.times do |i|
      article.comments.create!(user: comment_users.first, body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris
      quis mauris turpis. Curabitur nec cursus lectus. In purus elit, bibendum in
      odio in, interdum porta neque. Nullam ultricies metus id lobortis interdum.
      Mauris volutpat nisl ac felis interdum ornare. Aenean interdum sollicitudin
      risus, et condimentum dolor molestie non.", article_id: i, created_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now)
    end
  end
end

def setup
  new_users = create_users(10)
  new_articles = create_articles_for_users(new_users, 5)
  new_comments = create_comments_for_articles(new_articles, new_users, 10)
end

setup
```

I think the problem is within the `create_articles_for_users` - when using puts on the new_articles variable its displaying a User object

```
#<User:0x0000000105afc778>
#<User:0x00000001062da148>
#<User:0x00000001062935e0>
#<User:0x00000001061dca98>
#<User:0x0000000106016060>
#<User:0x0000000105e7ec48>
#<User:0x00000001060de240>
#<User:0x00000001063776c8>
#<User:0x00000001065b0b60>
#<User:0x000000010663a158>
```

Changing `comment_users = users.reject{|user| user[:id] == article.user}` to `comment_users = users.reject{|user| user[:id] == article[:id]}` I get `rails aborted! ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Article must exist /Users/lucas.shaw/rails_odin_project/db/seeds.rb:81:in` block (2 levels) in create_comments_for_articles'`

Comment: You need to create the users first. Then loop through those to create the articles, otherwise you will not have the full user set for commenting.  For the comments, to get a random user who is not the author... ```comment_user = User.where.not(id: user.id).sample```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some strong advice: never just write script code.  Always assume you're going to use some portion of it later - especially since actually structuring things is practically free.

```
def create_users(number)
  number.times.map{|i| User.create!(...)}
end

def create_articles_for_users(users, number)
  users.map do |user|
    number.times.map do |i|
      user.articles.create!(...)
    end
  end
end

def create_comments_for_articles(articles, users, number)
  articles.map do |article|
    comment_users = users.reject{|user| user == article.user}
    number.times.map do |i|
      article.comments.create!(user: comment_users.shuffle.first, ...)
    end
  end
end

def setup
  new_users = create_users(10)
  new_articles = create_articles_for_users(new_users, 1).flatten
  new_comments = create_comments_for_articles(new_articles, new_users, 10)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting `undefined method `user' for #<User id: 0, email: "user_email0@email.com", role: "user", created_at: "2023-06-01 08:49:24.141073000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-06-01 08:49:24.141073000 +0000", username: "0_username">`. I've updated the question, I think its creating User object for the create_articles_for_users method.

Comment: My mistake!  I did users.each and it should have been users.map.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am now getting `NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for 1:Integer`. When printing out new_articles its now returning an integer. Any ideas are highly appreciated :)

Comment: More maps needed.